# Problema com Core Data no iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, core-data

Estou com um problema entre o iOS 8 e o iOS 7. Estou utilizando o Core Data, tenho uma entidade chamada `Pessoa` (`NSManagedObject`), só que ao efetuar um update nos dados acontece um `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, somente isso, nenhuma outra descrição ou erro mais.

Acontece no seguinte trecho:

`let batchUpdateRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "Company")`

Estranho pois no **iOS 8 funciona** normalmente e atualiza os dados.

O código do método basicamente é:

```
func update (people: People) {
        var error: NSErrorPointer = nil

        //O erro ocorre aqui
        let batchUpdateRequest       = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "People")

        batchUpdateRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "idObject == \(people.idObject)")            
        batchUpdateRequest.propertiesToUpdate = [
            "name" : people.name,
            "phone" : people.phone,
            "address" : people.address,
            "email" : people.email
        ]
        batchUpdateRequest.resultType = NSBatchUpdateRequestResultType.UpdatedObjectsCountResultType
        let result = managedObjectContext?.executeRequest(batchUpdateRequest, error: error) as NSBatchUpdateResult
    }
```

Ja tentei alterar para:

`let batchUpdateRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "Company" as NSString)`

Porém tudo sem sucesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não vai conseguir usar o `NSBatchUpdateRequest` no **iOS 7**, pois este só foi introduzido no **iOS 8**. Referência: [iOS 8.0 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/CoreData.html)

No iOS 7 o que você terá que fazer é iterar entre os objetos e fazer as alterações uma a uma.